# Time dilation calculation in PHP returns divide by zero?

Tags: php, time, physics

After doing quite a bit of digging, I found the calculations to get time dilation in space based on velocity in marks of lightspeed in a vaccuum.

I am using the earth rotation base (will account for earth speed later), as the start number to up-convert into lightyear time.

The code I have written is as follows :

```
$now = (time() / 86164.098903691);

echo 'Days: ' . $now;
echo 'Lightspeed: ' . dilation(0.95, $now);


function dilation($lightspeed, $elapsed) {
    $t = $elapsed/(((1-($lightspeed*299792458)^2)/(299792458^2))^0.5);
    return $t;
}
```

Basically, the numbers are as follows :

- `299792458` is the speed of light in a vaccum (m/second)
- `86164.098903691` is the exact seconds for a complete rotation of the
  earth on it's axis (aka, one earth day -- not to be confused with
  solar days which fluctuate based on distance of the sun, and moon).
  Reference:  International Earth Rotation and Reference Systems
  Service.

The formula is a conversion to php from here >> http://www.phy.olemiss.edu/HEP/QuarkNet/time.html << which seems to accurately represent time dilation based on velocity.

The problem I am having with this code is I get the following error ::

```
[Sun Apr 13 18:47:39.413743 2014] [:error] [pid 3028:tid 1328] [client 127.0.0.1:60754] PHP Warning:  Division by zero in C:\\server\\www\\127.0.0.1\\htdocs\\test.php on line 31
```

However it is not clear as to why as all variables seem to be accounted for. Could you please point out why (a solution) this is happening ?

### Addendum

The following code does not return any errors --

$time = time();
$now = ($time / 86164.098903691);

```
$lightspeed = 0.95;
//echo ($lightspeed*299792458)^2;

$speed1 = (1-(($lightspeed*299792458)^2));
$speed2 = ((299792458^2)^0.5);
$dilation = ($now/($speed1/$speed2));

echo 'Unix: ' . $time . "\n";
echo 'Days: ' . $now . "\n";
echo 'Speed1: ' . $speed1 . "\n";
echo 'Speed2: ' . $speed2 . "\n";
echo 'Dilation: ' . $dilation . "\n";
```

Comment: I reckon your equation somehow gets down to $elapsed/0 - this is the most likely scenario.  Probably the second part gets so close to "1-1" that all the valuable digits are lost.  

You can try and brake it up: do multiple calculations, one for each part, and print the values as you go; it'll give you the answer.

Comment: Let me try breaking it down in bits and see what happens.  It shouldn't be 0 though---  my guess is php is having trouble with the big numbers (or fractions).  Give me 5 minutes and will addendum my Q with the calculation breakdown

Comment: `$t = $elapsed/(pow((1-pow($lightspeed*299792458,2))/pow(299792458,2)),0.5);`

Comment: @MarkBaker - close.  Actual is :  `$t = ($now / pow(1-pow($lightspeed * 299792458,2)/pow(299792458,2),0.5) );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` is a bitwise xor operator in PHP, not an exponential operator

use

```
pow($lightspeed*299792458,2)
```

and

```
pow(299792458,2)
```

instead

Comment: hmm... that could be it :)   testing.

Comment: I just tried that and am getting a E long (aka :  `-5.9942699954042E-5`).  You wouldn't happen to know how to convert that into a usable number ?

Comment: Figured it out -- had formula wacked out after switching to pow().  End result working is -- `$t = ($now / pow(1-pow($lightspeed * 299792458,2)/pow(299792458,2),0.5) );`